# Message box appears on every worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I'm using the following code to populate a message box when today's date is entered in Cell H3. The problem is that the message box is appearing on every worksheet. I only want it on the sheet I place the code in (in this case, "Sheet1") and I want the message to keep popping up until the date is deleted. Please help!

```
Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Dim myMessage As String

    myMessage = ""

    If Range("H3").Value = Date Then
        If (myMessage <> "") Then myMessage = myMessage & vbCrLf
        myMessage = myMessage & "You have a new message. Delete the date next to the message box to acknowledge this message."

    End If

    If (myMessage <> "") Then MsgBox (myMessage)

End Sub
```

Comment: try putting `Me.` in front of `Range("H3").Value`

Comment: Didn't work. I don't know if I have to specify "Sheet1" at any point in the code.

Comment: Do you want this ran when "any" H3 cell is changed? Do you want it to be ran when H3 is changed on sheet 1, sheet 2, sheet 3, etc? I assume not

Comment: I only want the message box to pop up on Sheet1 when any date is entered in cell H3 on Sheet1.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do this is to create a macro with the subroutine you created and then call it from the Worksheet_Change event on the worksheet you are working off of.

First: Create a Macro (Developer > Macros)

Next: Put your code into the macro adding a variable to pass the sheet name to.

```
Sub Worksheet_Calculate(SheetName as String) 
Dim myMessage As String

myMessage = ""

If Sheets(SheetName).Range("H3").Value = Date Then
If (myMessage <> "") Then myMessage = myMessage & vbCrLf
    myMessage = myMessage & "You have a new message. Delete the date next to the message box to acknowledge this message."

End If

If (myMessage <> "") Then MsgBox (myMessage) 
End Sub
```

Finally: Go back to the workbook and right click on the sheet tab. Select View Code and 
add a Worksheet_Activate() subroutine which calls the subroutine created in the macro (passing the sheet name as a parameter).

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Worksheet_Calculate "Sheet1" 
End Sub
```

Now, the only time the messagebox will appear is if the designated cell on the designated sheet has the designated data.

Comment: The message box only pops up one time (When the date is entered). I need it to pop up every time I click out of the sheet and back in again, as long as a date is in that cell.

Comment: In that case, just change the Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) event to a Worksheet_Activate() event.  This should then do what you want.

Comment: Nothing happened. It no longer prompts the message box at all

Comment: This worked when I demo'd it for myself first so I suspect either the wrong routine was changed, there is some logic issue/typo that isn't breaking it entirely but is causing it to not fire, or the nature of the issue is different than what my understanding of it is (the last being less likely because it worked for you the way I had designed originally where it fired when a date was entered).  I would suggest putting breakpoints at the Activate() routine and at each step in the macro routine and step through each line to see where it stops.